# Mining rig questions

Tags: mining-hardware

sorry if this question is for another place but I've been wondering are mining rigs mobile( can i move them from room to room in my place with ease without wondering if they will boot up properly or..? ) and can a rig be placed in a room with some moisture ( nothing big,its a room where my deep freezer,foodstuffs and tools are, something like a cellar...)
Also is it better to get amd based gpus or nvidia?

Answer (score 1):

Mining Rig is a computer system that is used for mining cryptocurrencies. This rig can be a devoted miner where it was appropriated, built and operated specifically for mining or it could differently be a computer that fills other needs, such as opearting as a gaming system, and is used to mine only on a temporary basis. "Mining rig" is a ideomatic metaphor for a single computer system that performs the compulsory computations for "mining".

Comment: OK, this answers all of my questions.